# Python Flask not committing data to database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to simply commit something to my database but for whatever reason when I submit my form it always gives me:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was
> unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
> there is an error in the application.

I cannot find out why this is happening, my code all looks fine and functions fine.

This is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, url_for, g
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

#Connect to MySQL db
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'forum'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 8889

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/signup', methods=["POST"])
def signup():
    username = str(request.form["username"])
    password = str(request.form["password"])
    cursor = mysql.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(%s, %s",(username, password))
    mysql.commit()
    redirect(url_for("login"))

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html", )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my index.html:

```
<h1>Simple Login Form</h1>

<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" required/>
    <input type="password" name="password" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you have a missing closing parenthesis in your query

Answer (score 0):

You haven't fully closed your parenthesis in `cursor.execute()` function. Try this:

```py
# ...

app.route('/signup', methods=["POST"])
def signup():
    # ...
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(%s, %s)",(username, password))
    mysql.commit()
    redirect(url_for("login"))
# ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I have tried this and I am still getting Internal Server Error... any clue why? Is it something with my app.config?